# How do I make dropdown boxes work without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made dropdown buttons using javascript for a school project, but the task requieres that everything javascript related should also work without javascript. What can I do to make these buttons work both with and without javascript. I would preferably like them to be open all the time when JS is not present

EDIT: Forgot to add ContainerReward in css.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="ContainerReward">
    <div class="dropdown">10km/week</div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">20km/week</div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">30km/week</div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">40km/week</div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">50km/week</div>
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ContainerReward {
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: 4;
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: 6;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;

background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown {
margin: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #BCEBCB;
color: #000000;
cursor: pointer;
padding:  18px;
text-align: center;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .dropdown:hover {
background-color: #93B48B;
}

.panel {
margin: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: #F7FFF6;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                    panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
```

https://codepen.io/michalpajestka/pen/GRqeVWV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this checkbox approach. You need to modify your html like with something like this.

```
<div class="ContainerReward">
    <label for="tenkm" class="dropdown">10km/week</label>
    <input class="dropdown_input" type="checkbox" id="tenkm" />
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <label for="twentykm" class="dropdown">20km/week</label>
    <input class="dropdown_input" type="checkbox" id="twentykm" />
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <label for="thirtykm" class="dropdown">30km/week</label>
    <input class="dropdown_input" type="checkbox" id="thirtykm" />
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <label for="fortykm" class="dropdown">40km/week</label>
    <input class="dropdown_input" type="checkbox" id="fortykm" />
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
    <label for="fiftykm" class="dropdown">50km/week</label>
    <input class="dropdown_input" type="checkbox" id="fiftykm" />
    <div class="panel">
        <p>K</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS like this.

```
.ContainerReward {
display: grid;
grid-column-start: 3;
grid-column-end: 4;
grid-row-start: 2;
grid-row-end: 6;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown {
margin: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #BCEBCB;
color: #000000;
cursor: pointer;
padding:  18px;
text-align: center;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #93B48B;
}
.dropdown_input {
  display: none;
}
.dropdown_input:not(:checked) + .panel {
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: #F7FFF6;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This should work for your use case.

Here's the pen to this example

https://codepen.io/mudassirzr/pen/bGeZXQB

Comment: Thank you so much! But I got a little problem though. When I used this code and ran the website in Chrome, checkboxes started to appear below every button after I clicked on them, even though they didn't appear on codepen.

Comment: This should work on all the browsers, please try hard refreshing your tab. If this helped please accept the answer.

Comment: It worked now. I did something wrong with the code on my side. However though, I forgot to mention that the panel boxes that appear after clicking on the button are transparent instead of white. I forgot to add a part of the code to the CSS, so I'm gonna update this post right away.

Comment: I've updated the answer and pen. You need to add display: grid; to .ContainerReward class otherwise all the other grid properties won't work with these.

Comment: Unfortunately, the panels are still transparent even though I used display grid...

Comment: you can simply add .panel { background: #fff; } to make it white background. simple!

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but one that will point you in the right direction (and hopefully learn more along the way)

You need something that can toggle between two "states" to represent the "open" and "closed" behaviour of a dropdown, something that does the natively without javascript, this sounds like a checkbox could be of some use? You can go between it being "checked" and "unchecked", there is a css pseudo class ":checked" that you might be able to use to control the open and closed styles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried something similar before with checkboxes. It was on a navigation bar with a dropdown when on mobile mode. The problem is that I needed to create a hamburger menu with CSS for the checkbox button. I want the entire dropdown button to be clickable.

Comment: This could be achieved with the checkbox approach. You can make the checkbox fill it's parent container. In this way, the entire container will be clickable thereby activating the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could also use the native `<select>` and `<option>` elements that are exactly for this. It is even automatically accessible. No JavaScript needed.</s>

Ah, I see, apparently I can't read. You are looking for an accordion, and not a dropdown. Then I suggest using `<details>` and `<summary>`. They also work natively in most modern browsers.